# Django annotate and aggregate with division

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following code:

```
    result = Training.current\
        .annotate(per_training=ExpressionWrapper((Count('trainingregistration') / F('capacity')) * 100, output_field=FloatField()))\
        .aggregate(Avg('per_training'))
    result = round(result['per_training__avg'], 2)
    print(f'Average occupancy per training: {result}')
```

I have verified that the `current` model manager works on other aggregations.

I want to calculate the average capacity per training by dividing the number of registrations (which have a `ForeignKey` to `Training`) by the training `capacity`, but this value always comes out to `0.00` and thus gets averaged to `0.00`. What am I doing wrong here?